# WordPress doesn’t load css and js files after installing on server

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

After moving my local wordpress installation to my webspace, wordpress doesn’t load css, js and some image files. The page displays only text without any styling or functionality (see [Click here](http://relaunch-saferdrive.de)).

What am I doing wrong? Hope you can help me..

Comment: i get 500 internal server error response codes. take a look at your logs

Comment: As @RolandStarke said your assets, like style.css, are giving 500 errors; meaning the file is not where you are calling it from. Make sure to copy all theme files over and adjust your Settings/General urls to the correct, new, url. I see your theme style.css called twice too, which might break the entire theme loading at all.

Comment: it's looks like your wordpress installation url on the database and the wordpress code directory are not match so the assets trying to load from not exists url (wordpress core is still loading because of htaccess rewrite). check your database for the wp_options table and column "option_name", search for "siteurl", the value in "option_value" column should be "...//relaunch-saferdrive.de", if it's "...//relaunch-saferdrive.de/saferdrive" and your wordpress code directory in the root so it means that this is the problem. do the check and keep us up to date.

Comment: @Eran.E 
You're right. I have updated the 'siteurl' and 'home' in the database or entered the correct url. The page is working again and I can log into the backend. Still missing some pictures and the styling of the page is unfortunately broken.

Comment: show me where the problem at, for now i can't find broken assets. in general, images that you'r attaching to posts inside "the content" are getting saved in the database with the rest of the content so the server will try to load those images from those old url's, also guid's of media posts and more. you will need to replace those old url's with the new ones. i recommended this tool: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ . put this in your root directory and run it with your search and replace url's, this should make all or for at least most of the job

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to import the css and js files

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts', 12);
function load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('filename', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/filename.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );


}
```

If the issues are with images make sure you hardcode properly.